# Goblin Battle Standard doesn't summon the goblin army

Tags: terraria-mobile

I'm on iOS edition (iPad mini) and I've just reached hardmode and made my Goblin Battle Standard. I have full health and really good weapons and armour my world is Crimson but for some reason it has no Crimson hearts in it which is annoying.

When I try use the Goblin Battle Standard all it does is show me holding it for a second and then doesn't consume. Can someone please help I really need the goblin tinkerer.

Answer (score 1):

Per the Terraria Wiki on [the Goblin Invasion](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goblin_Army):

> The criteria for a Goblin Invasion to occur at all is as follows:
>
> You must have smashed at least one Shadow Orb or Crimson Heart.
> At least one player must have 200 HP or more.
>
> If the player has not met both of these requirements, they will be unable to use a Goblin Battle Standard to manually summon the event.

If you haven't found a Heart to smash in your Crimson world, then you won't be able to run the invasion, either by chance or by using the Battle Standard.  If your world actually doesn't have any (I would try harder to find one first - I've not heard of that bug before, but anything's possible), then that world would never be able to run that Invasion event and you would have to generate a new world to be able to use the summoning item.